# Check if string contain a char or not Erlang

Tags: string, erlang

I want to check if the **string contains** a specific **character** or **alphanumeric number** present in it.

Eg.

```
Line = "23423+e324AB".
```

What will be the *best possible solution* to find if the string '*Line*' contains '*+*' symbol??

Thanks :)

Comment: Try `Ok = string:str(Line, "+") > 0.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, best is `lists:member(hd("+"),"fff+fdd")`.

Time execution is fastes

```
9> timer:tc(fun() -> lists:member(hd("+"),"fff+fdd") end).
{11,true}
10> timer:tc(fun() -> string:str("ff+ggg", "+") > 0 end).
{1965,true}
```

Comment: deep thinking!!  @Maryna :)

Comment: Why not `lists:member($+,"fff+fdd")` ?

Comment: @Hynek -Pichi- Vychodil you are rights, it is best one

Comment: @MarynaKrasnova: BTW, `lists:member/2` is fastest because it is BIF.